# onClick event does not work with xbl:inherits

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, onclick, xul, element

I'm developing a Firefox add-on and having a problem: onClick event does not work with xbl:inherits. Other attributes like value and src work well

Here is my code

Binding:

```
<binding id="CF-review">
    <content>
        <xul:vbox>
            <xul:label class="CF-review-url" xbl:inherits="onclick">[more]</xul:label>
        </xul:vbox>
    </content>
</binding>
```

Script:

```
function onReviewClick()
{
    alert("Something");
}

var elem = document.createElement("vbox");
elem.className = "CF-review";
elem.setAttribute("onclick", onReviewClick);
```

How can I set event onclick for xul:label element above?

Comment: Is the xmlns:xbl given in the document and not just xmlns?

Comment: Yes, I also include xmlns:xbl, xmlns:xul and xmlns:html

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, don't know if this would work:

Add a `<handler>` in your XBL that just calls `event.preventDefault` if the `event.target` is anything *other* than the particular label you want the user to click on. Then when they click on that label, `preventDefault` *won't* be called and it will just work, by virtue of the fact that they added an `onclick` attribute.